# Como deixar um Componente semi estático

Tags: c#, winforms, toolbox

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Criei um trackBar com 2 thumbs pelo user control , porem no form.design se eu arrastar o componente mudando a largura , bagunça o trackbar , queria tirar essa opção de arrastar para lateral , deixar apenas disponível pra cima e pra baixo , como os outros componentes que já existem na toolbox .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não ficou claro pra mim o que é "bagunça a trackbar". Consegue mostrar o antes e depois?

Comment: Adicionei as imagens para facilitar

Comment: Não tenho VS aqui comigo agora, mas dá uma testada nas `Anchors` pra ver se te resolver o problema.

Comment: Você quer impedir o componente de ser manipulado (ter suas dimensões alteradas por *resize*) em tempo de desenvolvimento? Por que? Afinal, é você que acerta o componente como desejar, não é? Aliás, eu to entendendo que o "antes" é a segunda imagem, e o "depois" é a primeira. Cuidado ao explicar as coisas na sua pergunta, porque caso contrário ninguém consegue entender e te ajudar.